# How can I ensure that the user always has an up-to-date Silverlight client?

Tags: silverlight

My users seem to want to keep the Silverlight client application live sometimes for days.  How can I ensure that a Silverlight client either idles out or updates when it is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box method to do this. The simplest way to do this would be to add a version web service (in whatever flavor of services you're using) to your server side. Then just have a timer class that fires as often as you see fit that would then trigger a call to this service to see what version was available on the server and compare it to the current version. If there was a new version you could pop a dialog to the user asking if they want the new version and if so just refresh the page.

Comment: Is there a way to auto increment build number on a Silverlight project in Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: Not in Visual Studio, but you can do it in TFS. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jjameson/archive/2010/11/29/incrementing-the-assembly-version-for-each-build-in-tfs-2010.aspx

Comment: BTW - For most Silverlight applications I use a manual build number that gets changed as soon as a release gets published. So if you just pubished 1.0 you would change the assembly version to 1.1.

Comment: Yeah, but that gets tedious when you publish ten times a day.  I don't have a choice.  We are a build and fix shop in the worst way. **sigh**

Comment: You might try looking at http://autobuildversion.codeplex.com/ it is out of date but could probably be updated for 2010.